# Delete runs slow in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, delete-row

My Delete Query run slow in Postgres

```
 delete  FROM Tab1  WHERE vdate =TO_DATE('20991231', 'yyyymmdd') 
AND DM =  'DK' AND T_CLASS_ID ='VK'and vk_id ='SM';
```

Explain Plan is

```
"Delete on Tab1  (cost=24181.99..172861.78 rows=0 width=0)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on Tab1  (cost=24181.99..172861.78 rows=456808 width=6)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((T_class_id)::text = 'VK'::text)"
"        Filter: (((dm_id)::text = 'DK'::text) AND ((VK_id)::text = 'SM'::text) AND (vdate = to_date('20991231'::text, 'yyyymmdd'::text)))"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_T_class_id  (cost=0.00..24067.79 rows=1482581 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: ((T_class_id)::text = 'VK'::text)"
```

Indexes are created still it is slow .Please kindly advise

DDL script for the table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tab1
(
    ID  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regcs),
    id_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    dm_id character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    vm_id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    id_cs_id character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    st_id character varying(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    id_code character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    valid_start_date date NOT NULL,
    valid_end_date date NOT NULL,
    ir character varying(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_id),
    CONSTRAINT fpk_id_cs FOREIGN KEY (id_cs_id)
        REFERENCES public.id_cs (id_cs_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fpk_id_dm FOREIGN KEY (dm_id)
        REFERENCES public.dm (dm_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fpk_id_vm FOREIGN KEY (vm_id)
        REFERENCES public.vm (vm_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.id
    OWNER to cdrdb;
-- Index: idx_id_cs_id

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.idx_id_cs_id;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_id_cs_id
    ON public.id USING btree
    (id_cs_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_id_code

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.idx_id_code;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_id_code
    ON public.id USING btree
    (id_code COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_id_dm_id

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.idx_id_dm_id;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_id_dm_id
    ON public.id USING btree
    (dm_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_id_vm_id

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.idx_id_vm_id;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_id_vm_id
    ON public.id USING btree
    (vm_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: Please rerun using `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to get the actual row counts, timings, and I/O activity. Update the question with the results.

Comment: It takes lot of time if i run EXPLAIN ANALYZE . It doesnt even produce output so only i run explain alone

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for this table and all available indexes on this table? And did you check pg_stat_activity to see if there are any locking issues?

Comment: The crucial question is whether there are any foreign keys referencing `tab1` and whether there are any delete triggers.

Comment: Are you sure this is the same table? idx_T_class_id is missing and the columns vdate, DM, T_CLASS_ID and vk_id are missing as well. This means that the DELETE query would fail.

Comment: Expanding on @LaurenzAlbe's comment, if there are tables with foreign keys referencing `tab1`, do the referencing tables have indexes on the relevant columns?

Comment: Explain alone simply does not give sufficient information to answer your question, you need to use EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS).

Comment: Hi Frank , Laurenz and Jhon, Thanks for your comments . I will check . I think Frank was right . When I replace with temp table with same structure it failed . Also I will check whether there are any delete triggers associated with  it . I will also check whether there are any indexes are there or not . Thanks for all  your replies . Let me check and will inform all

Comment: Hi Belayer , when I use Buffer , Analyze , Explain query running continuously without any results

Comment: What `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output do you get if you just run SELECT rather than DELETE with the same table and WHERE?

Comment: Hi All , I checked DDL of the table . It has alter constraint with no action on update or delete